# `UINavigationBar` curved extension?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, rounded-corners

In Apple's examples for customizing `UINavigationBar`, they demonstrate the possibility of extending the navigation bar for additional functionality by covering the bottom of the bar and recreating its drop shadow. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

I'm looking to do this, but with a curved extension. In other words, a semi-circle to make the entire `UINavigationBar` seem like it were a section of a big circle. **See attached:**

[image: design mockup]

The only way I've thought about possibly doing this so far is to make a very large but contained `UIView` with a large corner radius to emulate this curve. I did a test, but found that when the size of a `UIView` exceeds a certain size threshold/ratio, the edges start to distort and it looks as awful as it is inefficient and strange to have a massive but clipped `UIView`.

**Since device sizes vary and screen-orientation changes needs to be animated without the curve distorting,** is there any way to possibly produce this sort of curved `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569210/uinavigationcontroller-with-custom-shape-navigation-bar   This might help

Comment: @iAnurag that's with background images, which won't work given the constraints I mentioned (for handling rotations and various screen-sizes dynamically) ...

Comment: @jtbandes I was thinking about `UIBezierPath` but I wasn't sure how to make it work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I came out for now is subclassing `UINavigationBar` and drawing the shape you want using `CAShapeLayer`:

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    var pathLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        super.drawRect(rect)
    }

    func setup() {
        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 31.47))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(186.72, 42.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(0.5, 31.47), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(93.22, 42.5))
        bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(375, 31.47), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(280.22, 42.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(375, 31.47))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(375, -0.5))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0.5, -0.5))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 31.47))
        UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
        bezierPath.stroke()

        pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pathLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        pathLayer?.path = bezierPath.CGPath
        pathLayer?.lineWidth = 1.0
        pathLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        layer.addSublayer(pathLayer!)

        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30))
        title.text = "Title"
        title.textAlignment = .Center
        title.center = self.center
        addSubview(title)

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

The problem is that the added `pathLayer` will cover the layers of navigationbar's title and buttons. So if you set the fillColor of `pathLayer` to color other than clear color, these buttons and titles will be invisible.

To fix the issue, you can add the title and buttons programmatically after the `pathLayer` is added as I did, or use `insertSublayer` to insert the `pathLayer` behind the buttons and title as mentioned in this post [CALayer - Place sublayer below storyboard UIButtons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043130/calayer-place-sublayer-below-storyboard-uibuttons)

Comment: Hmm, does this have to be within the bounds of the `UINavigationBar`, though?

Comment: No, it can be out of the bounds of  `UINavigationBar`